# Tag [tag:fm] should be a synonym of [tag:frequency-modulation]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Came across this, and removed the [fm](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm)/[frequency-modulation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency-modulation) double tagging.

[Recommendation for good ressources on digital processing and D-QPSK](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36968/do-you-recommend-any-good-ressources-to-understand-digital-processing-and-d-qpsk)

So, I think, since this abbreviation is really common, can we please have the title-mentioned synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, we can do that! Which way do you suggest? <kbd>fm</kbd> as the tag and <kbd>frequency-modulation</kbd> as the synonym or the other way?

---

As suggested by @jojek, I've added [fm](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm) as a synonym of [frequency-modulation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency-modulation) so [frequency-modulation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency-modulation) is the main one. [See here.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/frequency-modulation/synonyms)

Please vote!

Comment: I suggest the `frequency-modulation` as the main one.